# Is There a Limit To How Many SHM segments you can create?

Tags: php, windows, shared-memory

i am creating a social network with php, i use longpolling and also need to have live comment replies, i could query my database for new replies in the longpolling page, but that would exhaust my database, so to avoid this, i create an shm segment for every comment, and then whenever there is a new reply to that comment i use the created shm to send the id of that reply to all users who are viewing the comment. so you get my idea. is creating a SHM segment for every comment going to cause me any problems ? for example if there are a million comments, what will happen ?

Comment: you really need to show your code to get a good answer ... I would highly recommend looking at node.js and socket.io to handle your real time comments.

Comment: the thing is, my code and everything else works properly, i have live replies, i am just concerned as to what might happen if i create millions of these shm segments.

Comment: what happens when you run out of memory ... application crashes, server crashes?

Comment: i wonder what others do to work their way around this ? not websockets because a certain amount of websites do this using longpolling.

Comment: what if i delete the segments after i am done with them, and create new ones whenever there is a new reply, could that fix it?

Comment: expirations, and garbage collection will certainly help

Comment: how do i implement them ? am i supposed to use something like memcached (short memory for your websites is their motto) ?

Comment: and if i don't use anything, would simply emptying the shm's after i am done with them help at all ?